# Writing and Reading a CSV simultaneously

Tags: csv, ms-access, testing

I am currently trying to setup an Access DB to track progress of test execution. What I would like to know if I set up an Excel database on one PC, how I will be able to read a CSV and update my Access database in real time? This particular CSV has data being written to it.

Comment: Normally, you would use Access as a front-end, installed on all computers, to allow data entry. You would then have another database (possibly Access or maybe something like SQL Server) installed on a server that is running 24/7, that is used to store the data in. Trying to use Excel as a "pseudo" front-end and pulling the data into Access, whilst achievable, is making life harder than it should be.

Comment: From what (how?) and when will the CSV be updated?

Comment: CSV is updated approximately every 2 minutes.